# Donwgrade da API 23 para 21

Tags: android

Tenho um app já postado na Google play que foi projetado na API 23. Mas agora surgiu um probleminha, pois tem alguns clientes que utilizam o Android 5.0.

Meu app é simples e não utiliza nenhuma função mais avançada do smartphone.

Será que posso fazer o downgrade ou sofrerei muitos problemas?

Comment: Pode dar o down-grade, pois se houver alguma biblioteca que não seja compatível com a versão do android a própria IDE irá te notificar do erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é perfeitamente possível diminiur a `minSdkVersion` para um app já publicado. O Google Play não faz nenhuma restrição quanto a isso.

Antes de fazer essa migração, recomendo testar seu app em dispositivos na nova versão para garantir que o seu aplicativo é 100% compatível com ela.